# Sending data to thingsboard with a timestamp defined by us

Tags: thingsboard

is there a way to send data to thingsboard with a timestamp defined by us??

The project is something like this...
i want to compare energy consumption before and after putting better windows in the building with an energy meter:

-- energy comsumption before installation --> i have data from the energy bills, and i want to send it to Thingsboard.
Something like... energy consumption and timestamp of energy bills

And than compare the 2 type of data...

tks for the help

already tried CSV, swagger API Post update telemetry

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can to it, in thingsboard client side api you can define your data timestamp when you are posting it (https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/#telemetry-upload-api):

Just set your payload with timetamp with this format:

```
{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}
```

Where "ts" is your timestamp in miliseconds.